# add sec.axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add the second x axis on the top of my ggplot. the first x axis shows the day of year and the second x axis is the Month according to first x axis dates. I tried sec.axis but didn't work.

```
b    Alt
148  1300
122  1300
130  1300
250  2000
300  2000
244  2000

  MonthId <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Agu", 
 "Sep", 
 "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
 FirstDay <- c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335,365)
 MiddleDay <- c(16, 45, 75, 105, 136, 166, 197, 228, 258, 289, 319, 350)
 g.b <- ggplot(CDD, aes(factor(Alt), b))
 g.b+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique( MiddleDay), 
             sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = unique( MiddleDay)))
```

Comment: Not sure if you can plot a secondary axis for a discrete scale. [This](https://codedump.io/share/jTG0XXtcl08D/1/duplicating-discrete-axis-in-ggplot2) might be helpful.

Comment: In 'aes(factor(Alt), b)' you are plotting Alt the x-axis. Then you use FirstDay with scale_x_continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to plot according to your data and description. For plotting the day of year in the main x-axis and the Month in the secondary you could use something like this:

Suppose that you have the following data:

```
MonthId <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Agu", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
MiddleDay <- c(16, 45, 75, 105, 136, 166, 197, 228, 258, 289, 319, 350)
b <- c(148, 122, 130, 250, 300, 244, 148, 122, 130, 250, 300, 244)
df <- data.frame(MonthId, MiddleDay, b)
```

Then use `sec_axis(~ . ...` with the desired `breaks` and `levels`:

```
q = ggplot() + geom_line(data = df, aes(y = b, x = MiddleDay)) 
q + scale_x_continuous("day of the year", 
sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . ,  breaks = df$MiddleDay, labels = df$MonthId , name = "Month"))
```

[image]